# GetUserAttributeVerificationCode in AWS Cognito without AccessToken

Tags: amazon-cognito

In AWS Cognito, I want to allow the user to login only after confirming both phone number and email. Is there any way similar to  GetUserAttributeVerificationCode API call where I can get the code without requiring the AccessToken from the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on similar situation where I want to send verification code through lambda. I tried post authentication lambda trigger to check if we get accesstoken but no luck(which is a good thing from security point of view)

So, unfortunately, there is no AdminGetUserAttributeVerificationCode or any other method that lets you send verification code to a user without access token. The idea behind that seems to be that only the logged in user should be able to send verification code to himself and not to anyone else.

May be this restriction is to prevent anyone(including AWS) to send mass verification codes to public without their consent (spamming).